# Phase shift estimation using cross wavelet

Tags: python, matlab, wavelet, phase

I'm in need of some help if you please.
In the attached text file, I have 3 columns, Column 1 is the altitude from 20 to 110 km with an interval of 0.1km.
The other two columns are signals.
Please calculate the phase shift between the signals in columns 2 and 3 as a function of altitude, ranging from 0 to pi.
Here is the data below:
Any solution is welcome.
[data_link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZrDrPSfPrOXwehfSIl0mLp37eO67zQDM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

**1.- Get the data in MATLAB workspace**

```
fileID=fopen('data_in.txt','r');

A=textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f')

h=A{:,1};    % altitude
y1=A{:,2};   % 2nd column
y2=A{:,3};   % 3rd column
```

**2.- 2nd and 3rd columns**

```
figure;
plot(h,y1)
grid on
title('row data')
xlabel('h');

hold on
plot(h,y2)
legend({'y1','y2'},'Location','northeastoutside')
```

[image]

**3.- Or perhaps by phase the following should be understood**

```
figure;
plot(h([1:end-1]),diff(y1))
grid on
title('dy1/dt   dy2/dt')
xlabel('h');

hold on
plot(h([1:end-1]),diff(y2))
legend({'y1^{\prime}','y2^{\prime}'},'Location','northeastoutside')
```

[image]

Perhaps `y1` `y2` are already in degree. Please let us know, thanks.